# German Characters in VB.net always displaying square box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, character-encoding, utf-8

We have a problem with German Characters in VB.net it always displaying square box.
We have an oracle database which the application is connected to. 
There is an existing PHP application that connecting to oracle database and now our company want it to migrate to Vb.Net.

We are done converting one of the system to Vb.net but we are encountering a problem with German Special Characters like äöüß when we select the characters in the database it always displaying a square box ���� however on the existing PHP application which also connecting on the same DB it display correctly.

Can you please help us on how to fix this? we are currently using UTF8 encoding in our vb.net codes. The oracle database has an NLS_Characterset of US7ASCII and an NLS_NCharacterset of UTF8. We already set UTF8 in the web.config file

We want to know what function in vb.net we can use to display the correct characters.

Comment: What kind of application is this?  Is it a web application?  Did you make sure to set the content-encoding of the web pages to UTF8?  Perhaps that's what you mean when you say "we are currently using UTF8 encoding in our vb.net codes", but it is better to be clear and precise rather than to expect people to figure out what you mean.

Comment: You will have to make a root cause analysis. For example, start with "when we select the characters in the database it always displaying a square box ���� " - find out where exactly do you see those square boxes? In the debugger, when you inspect the variables after the select? In the log file, when you write the variables into a file? Or only in the HTML code, created by the application? Find out where in your application layers the problem occurs.